# Android SDK not found in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a project in Android Studio that no longer runs on the emulator. I have checked the project settings numerous times and the path to the SDK is correct and I have even tried to create new SDK file paths. Even after doing a Gradle Sync the error that "local sdk path not found" still appears. Please help, I have tried everything I know and nothing on Google is seeming to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try option `Build > Clean Project`

Comment: I got the same error few days ago also. I don't remember exactly the that I did, but try close and reopen your Android Studio, maybe it resolve

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cachae and Restart did the trick for me. Go to `File -> Invalidate cache/Restart -> Invalidate and restart`.

Also check if path is correct in your `local.properties` file, available in your project dir.